# Network on Hyper-V VM for iSCSI storage for DPM 2010 testing

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi

I would like to add a iSCSI drive to one of our hyper-V VMs. We have the iSCSI network configured for the Hyper-V box, I just wanted to double check how can I achieve this for a VM on this Hyper-V box.

1. Add extra NIC to VM (for iSCSI)
2. Using Virtual Network Manager - allocate this NIC to use iSCSI of the Hyper-v host
3. Test by pinging

My Hyper-v server is a blade server, I am not sure if I should add a extra NIC for the hyper-v host, and use that NIC for iSCSI access (for the guest VM) or should I just use the same iSCSI NIC of the Hyper-v host for Hyper-v guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REALLY depends. You should havea separate physical NIC on the host for the iscsi traffic, but sometimes can get away with doing that on your backend NIC...

Way 1:

- Mount ISCSI drive on host, deactivate, map physical desk to VM.

Way 2:

- Add additional NIC in the VM
- Assign this NIC to the network that ends up on your NIC on the host where the ICSCI LUN is visible.
- Configure the NIC in the VM and mount the disc from there.